# where am I doing wrong in my signals in django?

Tags: django, python-2.7

I have defined a signal

```
 from django.dispatch import Signal
 user_status_change = Signal(provideing_ars=['request', 'email', 'status'])
```

I am calling this in the function:

```
 def setUserStatus(request):
 __name__="setUserStatus"
   .......
   r = user_status_change.send_robust(sender=__name__, request=request, email='xyz@gmail.com', status='Pause')
```

so when a user is paused setUserStatus function is call and then the signal is called.

I have defined a function like this

```
 @reciever(user_status_change):
 def setAlltoPause(sender, request, email, status):
    """Here we perform required actions"""
```

so whenever user status is changed, the function setUserStatus will be called and a signal is fired where setAlltoPause function should be executed.But setAlltoPause is not being executed, what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: You should pass `sender` parameter to `send_reobust()`. Also try using `send()` which does not catch any exception and may uncover underline problem.

Comment: Hi @Rohan I have used sender and also checked send() nothing is happening.

Comment: what file do you define your receiver in?

Comment: have you confirmed the `setUserStatus` function is actually being called?

Comment: as @Rohan stated, both when you `send_robust` and in your receiver should have `sender` as the first argument

Comment: Hi @Anentropic three functions are defined in separate files and I imported them. Yeah I am passing sender as the first argument
r = user_status_change.send_robust(sender=setUserStatus, request=request, email='xyz@gmail.com', status='Pause') the function setUserStatus is not being called I don't know why?

Comment: Where is the code that calls `setUserStatus` then? How does that get called?

Comment: when a user was paused by the admin, url will call the function setUserStatus which changes the status of the user in db.In that function I am firing a signal 'user_status_change', and then I am defining a function 'setAlltoPause' which will pause user related data in the db.

Comment: you earlier said "the function setUserStatus is not being called" so maybe the problem is not with the signals?

Comment: also it's important that your receiver function is in a file that is imported on startup

Comment: not setUserStatus, setAlltoPause is not being called..I have placed the function in the file that is imported on startup.

Comment: `__name__` is the name of the module, you shouldn't overwrite it! Use another name for your variable...